# perl: split one column into two

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a column in a spreadsheet that contains both a numerical ID and then an annotation. For example:

```
529120  30S ribosomal protein S3
```

I'd like to split that column into two where the first column contains the numerical ID (529120) and the second column contains the annotation (30S ribosomal protein S3).

The code I have so far only prints out the numerical ID for the first column and then terminates.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $annotationsFile = "/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/AnnotationsSplit.tsv";

    open( ANNOTATIONS, "<", $annotationsFile )
      or die "Cannot open file $!";

      while ( my $line = <ANNOTATIONS> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my @column     = split( /\t/, $line );
        my $annotationFull = $column[3];
        my ($annotationNumber) = $annotationFull =~ (/^(\d+)/);
        print $annotationNumber, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) with LIMIT=2:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($id, $annot) = split /\s+/, $line, 2;
    print "id    = $id\n";
    print "annot = $annot\n";
}

__DATA__
529120 30S ribosomal protein S3
```

Outputs:

```
id    = 529120
annot = 30S ribosomal protein S3
```